# Exporting from Org-mode to LaTeX ignores LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS

Tags: org-mode

When I try to export from Org-mode to latex using `C-c C-e l`, the contents of `LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS` is always completely ignored. Here's a minimal example:

**test.org**

```
#+LaTeX_CLASS: article
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [12pt,a4paper]

* Headline 1
  some text
```

**test.tex**

```
% Created 2013-02-18 Mon 12:12
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{test}
\author{John J. Camilleri}
\date{18 February 2013}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\vspace*{1cm}

\section{Headline 1}
\label{sec-1}

  some text

\end{document}
```

This is a clean version of Org-mode with no customisations. Any ideas? I don't know what else to try, yet it also seems too obvious to be a bug...

Comment: You example works fine for me.  What is your version number for `org-mode`?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure how to check.. I am using Emacs 23 on Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: `C-h v org-version`.  Mine is `7.8.03`, not the absolutely newest.

Comment: Thanks, it tells me 6.33x! Guess that's pretty old, I will look into updating it

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was an issue with an old version of Org-mode (I was using 6.33).
I have since updated to 7.8 and now it works as intended.